# "permission denied" while removing git directory

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I'm trying to remove a .git directory while using win7 and git-bash. here's my attempt:

```
$ rm -rf .git
rm: cannot remove directory `.git/objects/5e': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory `.git/objects': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove directory `.git': Directory not empty    

$ rmdir .git
rmdir: `.git': Directory not empty
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows 7 - Git-bash

```
$ sudo
sh.exe": sudo: command not found
```

git-bash in windows does not have sudo command.

Most probably, you used some git commands in command shell with elevated privileges. In windows 7 , your normal user and your user with elevated privileges have different powers. Try to do one of the following

1. Try remove that directory in windows explorer
2. Start git bash as administrator and run your rm command.
3. Try to change its permissions so that your normal user has full control of that directory.

Comment: I ended up using option 1 : Control Panel > Folder Options > View tab > check Show Hidden files folders and drives..

Answer (score 12):

Try to delete the folder after closing any of the IDEs you are using (Eg: Aptana Studio). When you have this project opened in an IDE, it won't allow you to delete the git heads.

Comment: In my case I had a git client with the directory open (GitKraken) so it didn't allow me to delete until I closed that.

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution to my issue in 2022

Answer (score 7):

In PowerShell

```
rmdir <foldername> -force
```

Answer [A] to Yes to All

Answer (score 4):

I faced with similar problem. It turns out that git makes certain files (objects) read only.
So you need to remove read-only flag recursively and then remove folder:

```
chmod -R a+w .git
rm -rf .git
```

Comment: This is a great solution for an automated environment in Windows, if you have UnxUtils.

Answer (score 2):

For windows->

- Go to start Menu, search Git Bash and select 'Run as administrator'
- Using cmd commands, enter the folder which has .git folder
- Use this command to remove .git folder -> rm -rf .git

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in macOS terminal.

I didn't work out what caused it, but when I closed the terminal and opened a new tab everything worked as expected.

Answer (score -3):

### Easy, try this:

1. > ```
   > sudo su root
   > rm -fr [repository name]
   > or you can do — sudo rm -fr [repository name]
   > ```
2. If you don't want to remove everything, put "-fird" instead of
   "-fr", so you can choose which one you want to remove.

With this you solve this permission error!

### IMPORTANT:

Errors like "permission denied" happen because only super users can grant your request, in this case, only people with root can do this, and then we elevate the user privileges.

---

In this process it is necessary put the password!